# wordpress offload CSS and JS and upload to GCP CDN bucket

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, cdn

I am looking way to offload JS and CSS of **WordPress** to the GCP CDN bucket so I can serve them via CDN.

I am minifying JS and CSS using the plugin so looking for a way if any existing plugin available in WordPress which can sync or upload CSS & JS files to the GCP cloud storage bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check [WP-Stateless plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/)
This plugin copies files from your WordPress site to Google Cloud Storage automatically as they are uploaded to the media library. It then offers different modes, such as backing up a copy of your media or even deleting the media from WordPress and serving up from Google Cloud Storage or a CDN.

Also, I have found a good guide that can help you with your task

[**WordPress Google Cloud Storage – How to Offload Your Media**](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-google-cloud-storage)

#### Edit 1

You can choose manually the file type you need:

[image]

Field description: Define the file types you would like supported. Separate each type by a space.

This field should also be supported by a wp-config constant (WP_STATELESS_MEDIA_BODY_REWRITE_TYPES)

```
 define('WP_STATELESS_MEDIA_BODY_REWRITE_TYPES', 'jpg jpeg png gif pdf');
```

#### Edit 2

Another option for integrating Google Cloud Storage with your WordPress site is to use the equally awesome free [WP Offload Media Lite plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) (or premium WP Offload Media) from [Delicious Brains Inc](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/).

This plugin automatically copies images, videos, documents, and any other media added through WordPress’ media uploader to Google Cloud Storage.

This plugin uploads the files  to your server first, then copied to the bucket, and then you need to remove it from your server, according with the [official documentation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/), there is an option to automatically remove the files from your server once they are copied to the bucket.

Additionally, you could find a good guide in this link: [**How to Set Up a Custom Domain CDN for Google Cloud Storage**](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/doc/how-to-set-up-a-custom-domain-cdn-for-google-cloud-storage/)

Comment: hi thanks for writing answer i am currently using wp-stateless. but i have tried it not uploading js or css file from wp-content/cache folder. there are modes CDN, stateless but i have tried all

Comment: No doubt stateless working like a charm for images and media.

Comment: @chagan I have updated my answer, please check my last comment.

Comment: thanks for writing an answer but i have doubts will it sync JS and CSS and also to CDN ?

Comment: which version of plugin are you using it's not available for me i am using latest one. 3.0.3

Comment: I have version 3.0, I will update and try to reproduce with the last version.

Comment: thanks for it still i have doubt will it sync JS and CSS ? from which directory it will consider as a base directorey?

Comment: if we enable file replacement url it's coming for me now.

Comment: your answer is helpful that's why upvote but still it is not what actually i am looking for. i am looking to upload js and css to css bundle

Comment: some how i tried adding js and extension but still it's not working as expected i want to upload JS & CSS files from local to CDN bucket.

Comment: option you are suggesting is file replacement

Comment: @chagan I have added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: thanks for writing the answer i have tried both plugins but still they are not uploading my non media JS and CSS to bucket

Comment: It is supposed that there is an addon for WP Offload Media -- [Assets Pull addon](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/#addons) – Serve your CSS, JS and fonts via  CDN, But I have not tested.

Comment: i have tried adding both plugin with addon it's working but there is no option available which upload my JS and CSS to CDN bucket. it's replacing URL but after that also files should be present inside bucket and for that we have to sync or upload files.

Comment: @chang if you already purchased the Assets Pull addon you should have [email support](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/pricing/#email-support) I suggest to contact them or you can also contact with support for [WP-Stateless](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/)

Comment: thank you so much for all the help and suggestion wp offload working  like charm. thanks